# how to get (http.get) and display selected item in angular js multiiselect dropdown (custom directive)

Tags: json, angularjs-directive, dropdown

How to display data(in from of array inside Json) using angular js custom directive for the multiple selection in dropdown.

I want to provide editing facility to user using custom directive for the multiple selection in dropdown.

I am successfully getting a previously selected data from backend but not able to display those data (in form of array inside Json) using custom directive to provide editing facility to user.

```
<script>
//directive for a multi select dropdown menu used on a search page

myApp.directive('dropdownMultiselect', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                model: '=',
                options: '=', 
                placeholder: "@",
            },
            template:
                    "<div class='btn-group show-on-hover' data-ng-class='{open: open}'>" +
                        "<button class='button-default dropdown-toggle' data-ng-click='openDropdown()'>{{placeholder}} </button>" +
                        "<ul class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='dropdownMenu'>" +
                            "<li><a data-ng-click='selectAll()'><span  aria-hidden='true'></span> Check All</a></li>" +
                            "<li><a data-ng-click='deselectAll();'><span aria-hidden='true'></span> Uncheck All</a></li>" +
                            "<li data-ng-repeat='option in options'><a data-ng-click='toggleSelectItem(option)'> {{option.name}} <span data-ng-class='getClassName(option)' aria-hidden='true'></span> </a></li>" +
                        "</ul>" +
                    "</div>",
            controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.openDropdown = function () {
                    $scope.open = !$scope.open;
                };

                $scope.selectAll = function () {
                    $scope.model = [];
                    angular.forEach($scope.options, function (item, index) {
                        $scope.model.push(item.id);
                    });
                };

                $scope.deselectAll = function () {
                    $scope.model = [];
                };

                $scope.toggleSelectItem = function (option) {
                    var intIndex = -1;
                    angular.forEach($scope.model, function (item, index) {
                        if (item == option.id) {
                            intIndex = index;
                        }
                    });

                    if (intIndex >= 0) {
                        $scope.model.splice(intIndex, 1);
                    }
                    else {
                        $scope.model.push(option.id);
                    }
                };

                $scope.getClassName = function (option) {
                    var varClassName = '';
                    angular.forEach($scope.model, function (item, index) {
                        if (item == option.id) {
                            varClassName = 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok green pul-right';
                        }
                    });

                    return (varClassName);
                };
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide the code here?

Comment: HTML CODE: <dropdown-multiselect model="selectedDomains"  options="domains"></dropdown-multiselect>

Comment: Please add the codes in the post (edit the post). It is difficult to understand the codes from comment.